# Deploying MS Lightswitch applications

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can Microsoft LightSwitch desktop applications be deployed as a single executable?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the current options are:

- Desktop client, 2-tier
- Desktop client, 3-tier
- Browser client, 3-tier

Answer (score 2):

Desktop applications (Silverlight Out-Of-Browser) are installed using "Click Once". There is a setup program & a few other files that get put into the location that you specify when you publish it.

So it's not a *single* file as such.

Yann